# how to scrape <ul> <li> <a>

Tags: python, scrapy

I newbie in using scrappy. I want to scrape link in this website [harga-hp](http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/) . in this element like I share the picture

[image]

when I click on xiaomi it will link to the xiaomi page and then I will scrape the price and the name . can someone help me to fix this code.

```
import scrapy
from handset.items import HandsetItem
class HandsetpriceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'handsetprice'
    start_urls = ['http://id.priceprice.com/harga-hp/']

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css('ul.maker > a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)

        next_page_url = response.css('li.last > a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        yield {
            'Name' : response.css('li.name a::text').extract_first(),
            'Price' : response.css('.newPice::text').extract_first(),         
        }
```

and the items.py :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class HandsetItem(scrapy.Item):
    Name =scrapy.Field()  
    Price =scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css selector for 'urls' needs to path 'ul > li > a', just like in the topic of your question.

You also spelled 'newPrice' incorrectly in parse_details(), which will bubble up after you fix the urls selector.